# Nested loop of array of dicts doesn't work in Google Sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I want to loop a column `Text` in a Google sheet and assign values to columns `main_category`, `item_category` and `item` based on the value of `Text` which maps to an array of dictionaries for each rule applied. I'm struggling at setting up the nested loop for the dictionary.

Sheet structure / source data:

```
Text     main_category  item_category   item
-------------------------------------------------
Banana   
Tomato  
Choco
```

Desired outcome:

```
Text     main_category  item_category   item
-------------------------------------------------
Banana   Fruits         Yellow          Banana
Tomato   Vegetables     Red             Tomato
Choco    Sweets         Brown           Choco
```

My approach:

```
function process_actuals() {

  // Initiating an array of dicts
  var rules_array = [
    {contains: 'Bana', main_category: 'Fruits', item_category: 'Yellow', item: 'Banana'},
    {contains: 'Tomato', main_category: 'Vegetables', item_category: 'Red', item: 'Tomato'},
    {contains: 'Choco', main_category: 'Sweets', item_category: 'Brown', item: 'Choco'},
  ];

  // Get active Spreadsheet
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get sheet "Source"
  var sht = s.getSheetByName('Source')

  // Get the range where data is present in sht
  var drng = sht.getDataRange();

  // Get the range size 
  var rng = sht.getRange(2,1, drng.getLastRow(),drng.getLastColumn());

  // Get an array of values within rng
  var rngA = rng.getValues();

  // Set up loop
  for (var i = 2; i < rngA.length; i++) {

    // Get the search string
    let search_cell = sht.getRange(i, 1)
    search_string = search_cell.getValue()

      // Loop array of dicts and check if search string is within "contains" key
      for (var dict in rules_array) {

        // If search string is in contains key, populate row
        if (search_string in dict['contains']) {  // breaks here
          
          // Populate rows
          var target_cell = sht.getRange([i][2]) // main_category
          target_cell.setValue(dict['main_category'])
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I receive the error `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Banana' in undefined`.

Comment: I think you want `if (dict.contains.includes(search_string))`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use `in` to look for substrings. That's Python.

Comment: @Barmar that returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined` hmm...

Comment: You should be using `var dict of rules_array`. `in` iterates over the indexes, not the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When your `rules_array` is used, `dict` of `for (var dict in rules_array) {` is `0, 1, 2,,,`. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. This has already been mentioned in the comments.
- When `setValue` is used in the loop, the process cost will become high.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function process_actuals() {
  var rules_array = [
    { contains: 'Bana', main_category: 'Fruits', item_category: 'Yellow', item: 'Banana' },
    { contains: 'Tomato', main_category: 'Vegetables', item_category: 'Red', item: 'Tomato' },
    { contains: 'Choco', main_category: 'Sweets', item_category: 'Brown', item: 'Choco' },
  ];
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from "Source" sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Source');
  var [[,...header], ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for putting to the sheet.
  var v = values.map(([a]) => {
    var t = rules_array.filter(o => a.includes(o.contains));
    return t.length == 1 ? header.map(h => t[0][h]) : Array(3).fill("");
  });

  // 3. Put the array to "Source" sheet.
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

- In this sample script, an array for putting to Spreadsheet is created using the retrieved values and `rules_array`, and put it to the sheet of `Source`.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, from your question, it supposes that the header row of your script is `Text, main_category, item_category, item`. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> However when I log v it is empty, thus the macro doesn't populate anything. Do I have to further enrich your sample script before? Re process cost, we aretalking about a couple of thousand rows only

In this case, I'm worried that your Spreadsheet might not have the header row. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function process_actuals() {
  var rules_array = [
    { contains: 'Bana', main_category: 'Fruits', item_category: 'Yellow', item: 'Banana' },
    { contains: 'Tomato', main_category: 'Vegetables', item_category: 'Red', item: 'Tomato' },
    { contains: 'Choco', main_category: 'Sweets', item_category: 'Brown', item: 'Choco' },
  ];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Source')
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = ["main_category", "item_category", "item"];
  var v = values.map(([a]) => {
    var t = rules_array.filter(o => a.includes(o.contains));
    return t.length == 1 ? header.map(h => t[0][h]) : Array(3).fill("");
  });
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

- In this sample script, it supposes that your Spreadsheet has no header row. And, the order of values is given by `var header = ["main_category", "item_category", "item"];`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However when I log `v` it is empty, thus the macro doesn't populate anything. Do I have to further enrich your sample script before? Re process cost, we aretalking about a couple of thousand rows only .

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my sample script, it supposes that the header row of your Spreadsheet is `Text, main_category, item_category, item`. From your replying, I'm worried that your Spreadsheet might not have the header row. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet as the image? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: nice, that works like a charm! Although I dont fully understand what's going on. I'll deep dive into the code line by line. Thanks! :)

Comment: I nailed down the code but struggle with the return statement `return t.length == 1 ? header.map(h => t[0][h]) : Array(3).fill("");` What does this basically mean? And what does the `?` and `:` stand for? Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, `the ? and : stand for?` is the ternary operator. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) And, in this case, it checks whether `contains` of `rules_array` has the value of column "A", when it's true, each value of `rules_array` is returned, when it's false, the empty values are returned. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.